# Schedule Video Recording

Tags: video, python-3, picamera

The code below records video for 24 hours straight which is too much. I wanna schedule the record like from 9.00am to 3.00pm only 6 hours of video. Being a novice and newbie I don't really know how to proceed. Should I use cron to do that or any idea?

```
import picamera

with picamera.PiCamera() as camera:
    camera.resolution = (640, 360)
    camera.framerate = 24
    camera.start_recording('one_day.h264')
    camera.wait_recording(24 * 60 * 60)
    camera.stop_recording()
```